# Foreman server provision complains /tmp/ks.cfg

Tags: pxe-boot, kickstart, foreman

I installed foreman 1.9.0 on a redhat 7.1 and try to provision a centos 6.6 with the default kickstart and kickstart pxe.

I tried to modify parameters, but it complains all the time on the same lines.
Here are two picture about the problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIG8S.png

Here are the files:
http://pastebin.com/smL3na37

Comment: Can't help if we can't see the contents of that file.

Comment: I have added the files.